# tar gz file extract exclude folder "data"

Tags: php, tar, shell-exec, gzip

I have a little problem, I have a large 41gb file on a server and I need to extract it..

How would i go about it, the file is in a tar.gz format and it will take 24hr on a godaddy server and then it stops for some reason

I need to exclude a folder name data this contains the bulk of the data 40.9gb the rest is just php.

`home/xxx/public_html/xxx.com.au/data` << this is the folder I don't need

I have been searching google and other sites for day's but it doesn't work..

`shell_exec('tar xvf xxx_backup_20140921.tar.gz');` this is the command I use I have even used the 'k' to skip files and it dont work

I have used the `-exclude` command but nothing,

Comment: Instead of "extracting all, but skip this..." have you tried to "extract only this..." and pick up the folders that you actually want to pull out of the archive while leaving the data folder alone?

Comment: how would i go about this??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
shell_exec("tar xzvf xxx_backup_20140921.tar.gz --exclude='home/xxx/public_html/xxx.com.au/data'");
```

This should prevent the path listed (relative to the root of the archive) from being extracted.

Comment: If it still hangs, then your problem is that it takes a long time to read the archive, in which case you should figure out a different way to approach the problem. But, the command itself (tested on my machine) will indeed prevent the file listed from extracting.

Comment: no matter witch way i word it, the command will not execute..
shell_exec('tar xvf xxx_backup_20140921.tar.gz'); < this works
if i add " these then it wont work

Comment: You're getting a syntax error? See that my answer's code has double quotes on the outside and single quotes on the inside for the `--exclude` specification.

Comment: no error nothing just a white page loading icon spins for a sec then stops  << nothing

Comment: Add a `echo "Hello, World!";` to the bottom of the script to make sure it is not failing.